# Importance of learning rate in fine-tuning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I've gone through a few models for fine-tuning & I observed that whenever fine-tuning a model on a different dataset through transfer learning, the people usually keep the learning rate very low( e.g.: 0.0001). So what are the pros and cons of having a low and high learning rate while tunning?

Comment: "What I know about a low learning rate is that it increases the chances of over-fitting." Why is this true?

Comment: you might want to take a look at this link:- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.07120.pdf.

One important paragraph from the source:- ""There are many forms of regularization, such as large learning rates, small batch sizes, weight decay, and dropout. Practitioners must balance the various forms of regularization for each dataset and architecture in order to obtain good performance. Reducing other forms of regularization and regularizing with very large learning rates makes training significantly more efficient""

Comment: That paragraph makes a claim, that larger learning rates are a form of regularization, but the only citation is to the [tag:dropout] paper; there is not supporting evidence to the claim that large learning rates are regularizing. The paper provides some evidence that large learning rates *and* a cyclical learning rate schedule improve networks, but that is not the same as claiming that large (constant) learning rates are regularizing.

Comment: So what you say, there is no generality that low learning rate increase chances of over-fitting or low learning never cause over-fitting.

Comment: I’m not making any claims about that, I’m just trying to understand the reasoning in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. Actually, I was also saying on the basis of that paper. Maybe that's wrong. I can edit the question. Thank-you. Let me know if you gather any info related to pros and cons of low or high learning rate when fine-tunning

Comment: Learning rate is a hyper-parameter that you need to tune, regardless if it is training from scratch or fine-tuning.